# Regex match not returning group when using wildcard

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Why does this work (returns 25):

```
var match = Regex.Match("Age: 25 yrs.", @"(\d+)");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

But this doesn't (returns a blank group):

```
var match = Regex.Match("Age: 25 yrs.", @"(\d*)");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

There must be something fundamental about how .NET handles regular expressions that I'm missing.

Comment: It seems like it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is `\d*` also matches empty string. And `Match` finds only first match. And as we know, you can fit as many empty strings as you want in front of any string. So it returns the first empty one.

So if you do this, it does match total of 13 strings with `25` being one of them.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("Age: 25 yrs.", @"(\d*)");
foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Index + ":" + match.Value);
}
```

Comment: I guess the easiest way to do this is to iterate through the matches and find the first one that isn't blank.  That will be the first match that I actually want.

Answer (score 0):

`(\d*)` will try to take 0-infinite therefor the result will be infinite and this isn't valid.

You meant to use `(\d)+` this will take 1 or more digits.